# Convert Text time into DateTime variable c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I would like to add '2 weeks' to an existing `DateTime` variable?

If I have the following date: `2000/01/01` and add two weeks, I'd like to have  `2000/01/14`.

Comment: How about this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.adddays?view=net-5.0

Comment: Here's a partial port of moment.js.https://www.nuget.org/packages/moment.net/#

Comment: I changed your dates to ISO format as only 5% of the global population use the MM/DD/YYYY format and it's unambiguous using the international standard.

Comment: "two weeks" after 2000/01/01 should be 2000/01/15... unless I missed the point

Comment: What are your requirements?  Are "2 weeks" the only input you need to handle?  Can you get "x months", "x days", or "x years".  Do you have a way to restrict input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this class to convert string to Datetime:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class ConvertDate
    {
        public DateTime ToDate(string dateStr) {
            if (DateTime.TryParse(dateStr, out var date))
                return date;
            else
                return DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
}
```

And Test your work

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace ConsoleApp.Tests
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class ConvertDateTests
    {
        [TestMethod()]
        public void ToDateTest()
        {
            var getdate = new ConvertDate().ToDate("2000/01/01");
            var add2Weeks = getdate.AddDays(14-1);//-1 beacuse the first day is 2000/01/01
            var expectation = new ConvertDate().ToDate("2000/01/14");
            Assert.AreEqual(add2Weeks, expectation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to do this: `DateTime result = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).Add("2 Weeks");`

Comment: It is not very clear from the question.  I originally wanted to answer with the same code.  The code itself and good and I like that you wrote a test.  Shows lots of work and effort +1

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you are given an input of "2 weeks" and you need to convert it into DateTime.  Assuming there is a limit to what inputs you can take, you might just week to manually parse it and convert a "week" to 7 days (and multiply by 2).

Microsoft has a project that is designed to understand written text so you might try it if there are too many input possibilities.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text/tree/master/.NET